# Override Swagger path using application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using springfox-swagger 2.8.0. I want to customize my Swagger documentation and API version path based on my requirement. Able to modify the version path using application.properties and it is coming properly:

springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/v2/availability-service

http://localhost:8080/context-path/v2/availability-service

But want my documentation URL like below, how I can do that using application.properties entry or any method override.

http://localhost:8080/context-path/availability-service.html

N.B. http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui.html URL returning the documentation properly.

Can anyone please specify how to do it ? Any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
server.contextPath=/v2/availability-service
```

Comment: Thanks bp zhang for the reply. If we do this changing the context path then application URL will change as well; I just want to customize my swagger documentation path. It should be like below---------> http://localhost:8080/context-path/availability-service.html

Comment: sorry,I may understand it wrong.I know how to modify in the java file, but I don't know how to do it in the properties file.

Comment: Do you know how to do that using JAVA ? If it is not possible modifying application.properties then please let me know how we can do this using java changes.

Answer (score 0):

My Java code:The prerequisite is that your url has good naming and grouping rules.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@ConditionalOnProperty("swagger.enable")
public class Swagger2Config {

@Bean
public Docket createRestApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("contract")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.invoice.gateway.api.admin"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/admin/**"))
            .build();
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Web APIs")
            .description("Contract Interface")
            .version("1.0")
            .build();`enter code here`
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is that **you can't**. At least one of the reasons for that stems from this function in the [springfox.js](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/springfox-swagger-ui/src/web/js/springfox.js#L128) code where `swagger-ui.html` is hard coded

```
const getBaseURL = () => {
    const urlMatches = /(.*)\/swagger-ui.html.*/.exec(window.location.href);
    return urlMatches[1];
};
```

---

The longer answer is that you probably can get around that, depending on your requirements and how much work you want to put into it.

If you just want someone to *reach* the swagger-ui documentation from your specific link, a quick solution would be to redirect any requests to http://localhost:8080/context-path/availability-service.html to http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui.html

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController(
                "/context-path/availability-service.html",
                "swagger-ui.html"
        );
    }
}
```